# Reuse socket after connect() fails with WSAETIMEDOUT?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winapi, windows-server-2012-r2

Our software had problems connecting to a SIEMENS PLC. We created a socket and continually did connect() on it, always receiveing WSAETIMEDOUT. Telnetting to the PLC on the exact same IP and port worked. Pseudocode below:

```
// Does not work
SOCKET reconnect(char* ip) {
    SOCKET sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr = make_addr();
    int err;

    while(1) {
        err = connect(sock,(struct sockaddr FAR*) &addr,sizeof(addr));
        if( err==SOCKET_ERROR ) {
            log()  // WSAETIMEDOUT logged here
            continue;
        }
        return sock;
    }
}
```

After changing the code to create a new socket for each connect() call, it seems to work...

```
// Works
SOCKET reconnect(char* ip) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr = make_addr();
    int err;

    while(1) {
        SOCKET sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        err = connect(sock,(struct sockaddr FAR*) &addr,sizeof(addr));
        if( err==SOCKET_ERROR ) {
            log()  // WSAETIMEDOUT logged here
            closesocket(sock);
            continue;
        }
        return sock;
    }
}
```

The first snippet has been running successfully in production for ~20 years, across multiple versions of Windows. I suspect it doesn't follow the specs though... Has there been any changes/updates to Windows Server 2012 R2 (which is what the customer is running) that changes this behavior?

**EDIT**

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx),

> If the error code returned indicates the connection attempt failed
>   (that is, WSAECONNREFUSED, WSAENETUNREACH, **WSAETIMEDOUT**) the
>   application can call connect again for the same socket.

... which makes this even more puzzling.

Comment: regarding this line: `struct sockaddr_in addr = make_addr();` a sockaddr_in, which consists of several fields, is not a native C type  Therefore, an assignment will not work.   Perhaps a pointer would work, But I would incorporate a call to memcpy()

Answer (score 1):

Your code was always wrong. A failed `connect()` always hoses the socket. You were lucky it worked so long.

Comment: See edits. According to MSDN, the first code snippet should behave correctly.